# Totalizar pares e impares, ver el número ganador en total y en cantidad desde n números

Tags: pseint

Yo creé un algoritmo en el que se ingresa una cantidad de números que los debo sumar y obtener un total en el caso de los números impares y los pares. También el número mayor de esta suma de números y determinar cuántos pares e impares hay, determinando cuál es par e impar el problema es a la hora de hacer la suma de números pares y la suma de impares, y dejar en claro cuál es el número ganador.

```
Algoritmo total_depares_impares
    Definir cantnumeros como entero;
    Definir pares, impares como entero;
    Definir cantpares, cantimpares como entero;
    Definir ganador como entero;
    Definir cont como entero;
    Definir num como entero;
    Definir sumadepares, sumadeimpares como entero;
    Definir sumaganadora como entero;

    pares<-0;
        impares-<0;
        num<-0;
        cont<-0;
        sumadepares<-0;
        sumadeimpares<-0;
        cantnumeros-<0;

        Escribir 'ingresa la cantidad de numeros que ingresaras';
        Leer cantnumeros;

        Repetir
            Escribir 'ingresa un numero';
            Leer num;

            si num mod 2 = 0 Entonces
                pares<-pares+1;
            Sino
                impares<-impares+1;
            FinSi

    cantnumeros<-0;

    Escribir 'ingresa la cantidad de numeros que ingresaras';
    Leer cantnumeros;

    Repetir
        Escribir 'ingresa un numero';
        Leer num;

        si num mod 2 = 0 Entonces
            pares<-pares+1;
        Sino
            impares<-impares+1;
        FinSi

        si sumadepares>sumadeimpares entonces
            sumaganadora<-sumadepares+1;
        Sino
            sumaganadora<-sumadeimpares+1;
        FinSi

        cont<-cont+1;
    Hasta Que cont=cantnumeros

    Escribir 'La cantidad de pares es: ', pares;
    Escribir 'El total de la cantidad de impares es: ', impares;
    Escribir 'La suma de los pares es: ', sumadepares;
    Escribir 'La suma de impares es: ', sumadeimpares;
    Escribir 'La suma ganadora es: ', sumaganadora;
FinAlgoritmo
```

Comment: Hola soy miembro nuevo en la pagina y tambien nuevo en esto de la programación, hay cosas que no se como ingresarlas en la pagina pero ya ire a aprendiendo. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé mucho de *PSeInt* pero de lo que puedo entender, y corrígeme si me equivoco, pero si por suma de pares te refieres el acumulado de todos los números pares que fueron ingresados creo que lo que deberías hacer es:

```
si num mod 2 = 0 Entonces
    sumadepares<-sumadepares+num
```

Así tendrías un acumulado y lo mismo *si no lo es*:

```
Sino
    sumadeimpares<-sumadeimpares+num
```

... y al final de la iteración (afuera del hasta que) compara `sumadepares` y `sumadeimpares`.